# jquery load with fadein and fadeout of content

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am using jquery to fadeout a specific div then I want to fadein new content to that same div.  Fading out works fine, but there is no fading in... rather it just 'pops' in immediately without any fade effect.

Here is what I have :

```
$('#account-info-form').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#tab_account_info').load('/account/ #account-info-form', function() {
        $('#account-info-form').fadeIn('slow');
        // show success toast
        toastr.info('Your profile has been updated.', 'Updated!');
        // reinitialize the form validation stuff
        AccountProfile.init();
    });
});
```

Comment: You may need to set the `display` on your `div` to hidden. Per the documentation, the `fadeIn()` should unhide the element with a nice fade effect.

Comment: @louis the `fadeOut` takes care of the hiding part.

Comment: Remember that when you load partial fragments, the actual ID of the element that's inserted is `result` (not `#account-info-form`). From the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Everything is working as expected with the wrapper fix mentioned below in the answer.  I did see in firebug that the response for my GET for the load call is the entire page /account/ and not just the id specified.  Is that a correct result?  From the doc listed it mentions retrieving the whole page with the rest discarded... is that supposed to happen after the GET which explains why the whole page is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the hidden element with a new visible element.  You should instead fade the containing element.  Based on your code, it would seem that is `#tab_account_info`.  If for some reason you can't hide `#tab_account_info` then you should add a wrapper element and fade/load that.

The reason this is happening is that when you use `fadeOut` an inline style is added which hides the element.  When that element is replaced (in this case through `load`) the inline style is lost.

Another alternative would be to simply hide the new element before calling `fadeIn` as so:

```
$('#account-info-form').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Won't using `hide()` right before the `fadeIn` cause the `#account-info-form` DIV to flash on the screen, then fade away?

Comment: @fasttrack It shouldn't.

Comment: Simple fix... yes, I actually have a wrapper around the form called #tab_account_info and doing the fadeout/fadein on this instead works as expected.  Between those calls I am refreshing/reloading the form which has the id #account-info-form.